# Proof of Knowledge/Data Integrity using Hash Function

Tags: hash, challenge-response, remote-data-checking

Objective: A verifier wants to ensure that a block of data M is also known to a prover. The protocol should exchange little information and should not leak information about the value of M.

Proposed Protocol:
*V -> P*: challenge *c*
*P -> V*: response *r = f(M, c)*

Question:
What is a suitable and efficient function *f*?

What comes to mind first is to use a hash function, such as *SHA2(c concatenate M)*, which may meet the objective. We could also compute *SHA2(M xor c')*, where *c'* is derived by repeating *c* as required to get to the length of *M*.

What concerns me is that *SHA2(M concatenate c)* will not meet the requirement. The prover could simply compute *SHA2(M)* partially up to the last full block of *M*, store the intermediate state of the hash function, and then delete the part of *M* that was already processed.
When confronted with a challenge *c* the prover can pick up the state where
it was left and finalize the computation without actually knowing *M* anymore.

Does anyone see such pitfalls with *SHA2(c concatenate M)* or *SHA2(M xor c)* or have other suggestions?

Comment: I don't see "such" pitfalls, but a challenge-response pair allows an eavesdropper to try as many guesses at M as it wants, so that can leak a fairly significant amount of information about M. ​ ​

Comment: I think you're looking for [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) with as key the challenge and as message the block? HMAC was basically made to prevent length extension attacks. You could also use SHA3 which is invulnerable to length-extension attacks.

Comment: It seems to me that a natural way to reach your goal and avoid your pitfalls would be to stretch c' from c using a pseudo-random generator, and then compute H(m xor c'). Also, the challenge c can be replaced by a key K, computed from a key exchange protocol (to avoid leaks to potential eavesdropper), but it involves public key operation; what are your efficiency requirements?

Answer (score 1):

From your question, I believe that what you are looking for is a *proof of storage*. I will point you in the direction of one [paper](https://cs.umd.edu/~jkatz/papers/pdp.pdf), and you can use that to look for other work on the topic.